# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter Give NoSuchMethodException If Build using Release Keystore

Tags: android, firebaseui

I know from https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/46, to fix NoSuchMethodException :

1. make sure that your TaskViewHolder class is public
2. if your TaskViewHolder is an inner class of e.g. your activity, make sure it's static

The solution is worked only if I build the app using debug keystore. But after I build the app using release keystore, I still get NoSuchMethodException. 
minifyEnabled=false

Tested on Android One Marshmallow Mito A10, Honor 6 and marsmallow emulator

Stack trace error:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder (FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:172)
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder (RecyclerView.java:5836)
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition (RecyclerView.java:5060)
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition (RecyclerView.java:4970)
android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next (LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk (LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill (LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren (LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2 (RecyclerView.java:3315)
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure (RecyclerView.java:2843)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18788)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5951)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1465)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:748)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:630)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18788)
android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins (ScrollView.java:1283)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure (ScrollView.java:340)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18788)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5951)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1465)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:748)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:630)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18788)
android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal (RelativeLayout.java:715)
android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure (RelativeLayout.java:461)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18788)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5951)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18788)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5951)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1465)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:748)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:630)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18788)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5951)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18788)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5951)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1465)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:748)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:630)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18788)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5951)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure (PhoneWindow.java:2643)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18788)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy (ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:858)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:670)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:606)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:844)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
```

My ViewHolder in seperate CommentHolder.java file with public :

```
public class CommentHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    implements View.OnClickListener {
TextView tvComment = null;
TextView tvUser = null;
TextView tvDate = null;
String emailComment = "";
String commentKey, catalogKey;

FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseDatabase database;
CommentHolder(View row) {
    super(row);
    auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    tvComment = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.comment);
    tvUser = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user);
    tvDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.datecomment);

    row.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() == null || auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail() == null) {

        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Harap login terlebih dahulu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if (!auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(emailComment)) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Anda hanya dapat mengedit komentar yang Anda buat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }


    final View form = ((Activity) v.getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_comment, null);
    EditText etComment = (EditText) form.findViewById(R.id.editTextComment);
    etComment.setText(tvComment.getText().toString());

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());

    builder
            .setTitle("Komentar Anda")
            .setView(form)
            .setPositiveButton("Kirim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    final EditText etComment = (EditText) form.findViewById(R.id.editTextComment);
                    DatabaseReference commentRef = database.getReference(MyConstants.FB_COMMENT)
                            .child(catalogKey).child(commentKey);
                    Comment comment = new Comment(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()
                            , auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail(), etComment.getText().toString());
                    commentRef.setValue(comment);

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Batal", null)
            .setNeutralButton("Hapus", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    DatabaseReference commentRef = database.getReference(MyConstants.FB_COMMENT)
                            .child(catalogKey).child(commentKey);
                    commentRef.removeValue();
                }
            })
            .show();


}

void bindModel(String catalogKey, String commentKey, String comment, String emailComment, String dateComment) {
    tvComment.setText(comment);
    String temp = emailComment.replaceAll("(?<=.).(?=[^@]*?.@)", "*");
    tvUser.setText(temp);
    tvDate.setText(dateComment);
    this.emailComment = emailComment;
    this.commentKey = commentKey;
    this.catalogKey = catalogKey;
}
```

}

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter code:

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment, CommentHolder>(Comment.class, R.layout.play_row
            , CommentHolder.class, commentRef) {
        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(CommentHolder commentHolder, Comment comment, int position) {

            Date date = new Date((long) comment.getLastUpdate().get("date"));
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
            String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
            commentHolder.bindModel(catalogKey, getRef(position).getKey(), comment.getComment(), comment.getEmail(), strDate);

        }

    };
```

My Comment.java :

```
public class Comment {
String uid;
String email;
String comment;
HashMap<String, Object> lastUpdate;

public Comment() {
}

public Comment(String uid, String email, String comment) {
    this.uid=uid;
    this.email = email;
    this.comment = comment;
    HashMap<String, Object> lastUpdateObj = new HashMap<>();
    lastUpdateObj.put("date", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    this.lastUpdate = lastUpdateObj;


}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public HashMap<String, Object> getLastUpdate() {
    return lastUpdate;
}
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve], including the Java stack trace associated with your crash and your implementation of a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes thanks. Just added java stack trace and my code

Comment: Just a guess: try making the `CommentHolder` constructor `public`, and see what happens.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are my hero !!!! Problem solved after I stress for 4 days

Comment: I'm not certain *why* that works, which is why I won't post an answer here. If minification is disabled, I cannot see how method visibility would change behavior between debug and release builds. But, I am glad that it is working for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CommonsWare, I will post your comment as an answer. In case someone else has the same problem with me, will find quick answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CommonsWare guess. The problem is solved after adding public to CommentHolder constructor.

```
public CommentHolder(View row) {
super(row);
auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

tvComment = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.comment);
tvUser = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user);
tvDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.datecomment);

row.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: @souttab Please edit your comment to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example :)

Comment: still facing problem

Comment: I am facing the same issue although my constructor is public. I have minifyEnabled true though, since I want to use ProGuard.